# Intermittent ECONNREFUSED after hot module replacement

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, webpack

I'm running a React app on webpack dev server and separately an Express JS server (not on webpack) at the same time. I have Hot Module Replacement enabled. The React app makes an API request when the page first loads.

When the app first loads, everything runs fine. When I change code in my React app and the module is replaced, I get the below error. If I refresh the page then it's fine again.

Any clue what might be wrong? Webpack dev server config also listed below along with my React code. Let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

Error:

```
[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:8080/api/link/token/create to http://localhost:3000/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Webpack Dev Server config:

```
devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,
    proxy: { '/api': 'http://localhost:3000' }
}
```

React app:

```
function PlaidLink({ linkToken }){
    const onSuccess = React.useCallback(async (public_token, metadata) => {
        try{
            let response = await fetch('/api/item/public_token/exchange', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ public_token })
                }),
                data = await response.json();

        } catch(error){}
    }, []);
    const config = {
        token: linkToken,
        onSuccess
    };
    const { open, ready } = usePlaidLink(config);

    return (
        <button onClick={open} disabled={!ready}>Link bank account</button>
    );
}

function LinkBankAccountButton(){
    var [linkToken, setLinkToken] = useState(null);

    const createLinkToken = async () => {
        try{
            let response = await fetch('/api/link/token/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify({})
                }),
                data = await response.json();

            setLinkToken(data.link_token);
        } catch(error){}
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        createLinkToken();
    }, []);

    return linkToken != null ? <PlaidLink linkToken={linkToken}/> : null;
}

createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<LinkBankAccountButton/>);
```